# What to do when a form's class becomes too large?

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

Currently my main form has a ton of event handlers because there are a lot of controls. It is very similar to a paint application. I have condensed it down quite a bit and I am sharing event handlers whenever possible but the class is still around 1,000 lines of code. I realize that may not be much to all of you but it is considerably larger than the rest of my classes.

I have refactored a lot of code to other classes but all those event handlers still increase the line count by a large amount. I also started using region blocks to separate event handlers in to groups and that is working rather well but I still would like to know SO's opinion on the matter as to best organize a large amount of form event handlers.

**Edit**: So I've been using partial classes and I must say, I don't really like them that much. I'm not sure what to do at this point.

I may go back to using region blocks as I'm not sure user controls will help my problem at all. Honestly I did not mind the region blocks that much. That class was the only place I used them and it organized the different sections of the code quite nicely (Menu Event Handlers, Toolstrip Event Handlers, Drag and Drop Support, et cetera).

Still, if anyone still has any other ideas or would like to elaborate upon any posted thus far I'd be more than appreciative as I am still looking for a better solution to this problem.

Comment: The simple solution.  Place the code that register the event handlers within a region block.  Get over "its over 1000 lines of code" because the code is required.

Comment: well, i kinda dislike regions; they tell there is too much stuff in one place, and grouping it in regions is just hiding the real problem

Comment: I do not like regions either. This is the only place I am using them in my project, and while they work quite well in this specific instance, I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Why don´t you isolate some of the code into worker routines and put those into a function library? Or into classes that encapsulate the specific functionality, and put them into a separate namespace? Then use regions to bundle the different event handlers into "Top level GUI handlers", "internal handlers triggered by control", ...?

Comment: Ah, you creates classes to encapsulate functionality, sorry, saw that just now.

Comment: I tend to agree with Ramhound. Regions and acceptance. If the code is necessary, you must live with its size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either split the functionality into separate classes (e.g. creating UserControls like Ed has suggested), or think about using `partial` classes (where one class can be split among many files).  I have found `partial` classes handy to group together related chunks of code, when the "main" class file is getting to large.  Sometimes this is the first step in refactoring those chunks of code into separate classes and/or controls.

It's hard to make a concrete recommendation without seeing the code, but those are some of your options.

Comment: What's the difference between having a partial class or a region block though? They both basically accomplish the same purpose and a partial class just adds complexity and files to the project and forces the programmer to look elsewhere for the functionality he's trying to find.

Comment: You're right that they are similar -- they are mostly just used for organizational purposes.  However, in cases like Designer-generated files or T4-generated files, partial classes allow you to separate out the generated code from your "real" code.  I think the ideal goal is to either split out some functionality into more granular classes, or make your own user controls if it's UI code that you are splitting out.  Moving chunks of code into separate 'partial' files is just an intermediate step that makes it easier to keep things organized (for me anyways).

Comment: I used to like "partial" feature, until I stumbled upon this link: http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/04/05/74442.aspx.

Answer (score 4):

1000 lines of code is nothing, and that should not be the basis for refactoring your code. Refactor your code where it makes sense; not just because a class contains more lines of code than your other classes. Some classes will require more code than others, and that's perfectly okay.

That being said, if it makes sense you can divide the controls into logical sections, and put them in user controls. Make sure that there is a good justification for doing so though, because otherwise you'll only be convoluding your code base.

I must remind you again though, don't split your code up *just* to reduce the lines of code.

Comment: While a form is a special case, if you have a class with 1000 lines I will bet that it violates [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: @TrueWill: Agreed. I have no quarms with dividing up code, just not for the sole purpose of reducing LOC.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already (you don't mention it) I would split out the various individual controls into UserControls.  You can handle all of the events from within the `UserControl` class and only expose those events that the parent form must absolutely handle.  These will likely be small in number and will drastically reduce the responsibilities of your main form.

For example, each tool button could live inside of a UserControl.  The canvas control can maintain and instance of the tools control and so on.  You can keep creating the composite controls where each upper layer becomes less complicated and most of the actual logic is handled below it.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't a bad idea actually! The only problem is that basically every event handler in my application is very different from one another so it seems like it wouldn't do much in this circumstance.

Comment: +1 for user controls 

You could have a ToolBoxControl  user control class. It could have all of those buttons on your paint apps toolbox. All of the click event handlers could be in the toolboxcontrol class and maybe it would have a field for the currently selected tool. One event handler in your main form could be used for when the toolboxcontrol's tool is changed (expose this handler in your ToolBoxControl's class). Then it's just one event handler in your main form to handle all of the clicking and changing of tools on your toolbox

Comment: This isn't a way to break up code. The purpose of UserControls is reusability. A UserControl shouldn't handle its own events, except to perform generic logic. It should expose events to allow subscription by the end user of the control. If the code belongs in the form, keep it in the form. If you really can't stand having a large class, and you've already factored out as much code to other classes as possible, then use partial classes to break it up.

Comment: @Charles: I very much agree. I think I'm going to go with partial classes for this one.

Comment: @Charles: Right, in theory, except in reality you rarely if ever need to reuse controls like that because they are catered to a very specific purpose in your application.  It *is* a good way to break up code in the real world and it works very nicely.  You can talk about the theoretical uses of UserControls as much as you like, but in practice it is a good way to hide implementation details.  The OP isn't making a control library here.

Comment: @Ed S.: The problem with user controls, though, is that most of the event handlers directly manipulate private variables like the map, and the user control would not have access to these variables. Instead of having regions like I currently do, I could instead move the region to its own partial class with a descriptive name. Seems like a rather clean and simple refactor.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  A user control can simplify things like button clicks and whatnot.  Like Steve said, imagine a ToolBox control which handles each individual tool button click.  All of these clicks trigger an event that the ToolBox exposes, SeelctedToolChanged or whatever you want to name it.  The EventArgs object of that event can pass the tool that was selected.  Now you can use the ToolBox control in another composite control which handles the single SelectedToolChanged event to do something more useful.  You should do whatever works best for you, but partial classes simply split

Comment: ...the code into multiple files.  I fail to see how that increases maintainability, especially when that code may very well need to be modified in the future.  Partial classes are great for hiding autogenerated code or code that probably never needs to be modified, but this is your application logic, not control initialization or something else that mundane.

Comment: @Ed: It doesn't hide implementation details, it just moves them to somewhere else. They were already hidden - in private methods. Sure, you can use UserControls for this purpose. But every UserControl you add to your form adds complexity. It's true that UserControls are almost always specific to one aplication, but personally I'll only create one if I have a group of controls that appears more than once. And even then, any form-specific logic around that user control still stays in the form.

Comment: @Charles: Then you will end up with huge main form classes.  I don't really understand your logic on this one... but whatever works for you and your team.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest of using more OOP solution. Do not add `UserControls`, as you add *more* *complexity*. Let's try to maintain complexity you *already have*, but make things more *clear*, cause this is what really you're asking for, I believe.

*DI like*. In practise if you need to handle a lot of events for a lot of contorls, create `ControlManagers`, which accepts in ctor the control and subscribes to its events.

So for every control you will have it's own manager.

Advantages:

1. Clear separated code in different classe, so easy recognizable in case of problems and my be more clear from architectural point of view.
2. You don't break down your architecture with a lot ot delegated events between tons of controls and subcribers (one subscriber per control)

Sure you will need organise, by the way, the data flow between different classes. But it's by my experience, haven't to be a big problem.

**EDIT**

An example *pseudocode*:

```
UserControl1 mycontrol1; UserControl2 mycontrol2; 
public class MyControl1Manager  {
    public MyControl1ManagerFor1  (UserControl1 uc1) {
          //subscribe to events of uc
          // here all code to handle events
    }
     public MyControl1ManagerFor2  (UserControl2 uc2) {
          //subscribe to events of uc
          // here all code to handle events
    }
}
```

and somewhere in code:

```
   MyControl1ManagerFor1  controlManager1 = new MyControl1ManagerFor1  (mycontrol1);
   MyControl1ManagerFor2  controlManager2 = new MyControl1ManagerFor2  (mycontrol2);
```

Something like this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this one, it sounds interesting. Can you provide some sample code to explain it a little more in detail?

Comment: Looks like a lot of work if you have many controls on one screen. Do you use this approach a lot?

Comment: Not a lot... but when you have a lot of them, you always can group them into "logical" groups. Forexaple: UserLoginManager, FileSendToFTPManager and things like this. And what you do basically is to move the code that have to be inside form's class into other classes, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a form that became really big. It showed the same information in many various ways. To reduce number of code in single file I used an approach similar to UserControls. All the GUI elements were placed on the form, but their initialization and handlers were maintained by helper classes. They were equivalents of UserControls, but without GUI interface. These classes were initialized in main form's constructor:

```
SideViewHelper sideView = new SideViewHelper(parentForm, gridControlMaster, gridControlDetail, buttonSubmit);
```

All the logic that handles the gridControl events, button events are handled inside the helper class.

After the initialization the main form (parentForm) may change state of many UI items by single call of ViewHelper's method.

These classes are created for this only form and are as lightweight as possible.